# Averaging values(they are angles) which are wrapping in o to 360

Tags: angle

I have a dataset which are angles and I need to average them to smooth out the noise. 
Dataset - > [354,357,355,2,352,4,352]  -- mean is 253.7143 ,which is wrong

Since there is a roll-off (I have 2 and 4 degrees in the dataset), how can I properly average these values so that I don't get wrong mean value?

As per penguino's answer ,

1. degrees to polar with r=1 and theta is degrees

   x=[0.9945    0.9986    0.9962    0.9994    0.9903    0.9976    0.9903]

   y=[-0.1045   -0.0523   -0.0872    0.0349   -0.1392    0.0698   -0.1392]
2. Avg'ed Value of x and y is [mean_x,mean_y]=[0.9953,-0.0597]
3. Transforming back from cartesian to polar

   ```
      [theta,rho] = cart2pol(0.9953,-0.0597)
   ```

   theta -> -0.0599   and rho -> 0.9971
4. theta is in radians so, radtodeg(-0.0599) is -3.4320
5. Since angle is in negative , subtract from 360 i.e 360 - 3.4320 = 356.5680
6. 356.5680 is the mean value of the dataset

Comment: What do you mean? Why is it wrong? Give us some more context

Comment: I mean to say that the data is in degrees (which is 0 to 360 ) and when I have a roll-off like this , averaging angles effects the mean value

Comment: I need to post-process this data to maybe wrap it somehow so that  the mean is around 350'ish

Comment: A brutal fix could be to make those 2 and 4 into 362 and 364, but perhaps you are looking for a general method

Comment: [This site](https://www.themathdoctors.org/averaging-angles/) is probably the most informative out there. However, it will be hard to combine all this information into one solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is:

1. convert each angle from polar (r=1,theta) to Cartesian coordinates (x,y).
2. average the set of coordinates to find a point within the unit circle.
3. convert back to polar coordinates (discarding r).

The returned value of theta is the averaged angle (in your example that would be 356.833).

Comment: Thanks Penguino.. I have done as you said and posted in the question. Can you please take a look into it and say if I have done correctly

Comment: You can just add together the unit vectors and take the direction of the result. No need to insist on having the result inside the unit circle.

Comment: My point was only that the average would always be in the unit circle. But yes, as long as you use normalized or unit vectors, you can just use the angle of the summed vectors. @Saira - that looks correct.

Comment: This answer has a bias. For example if the angles (in degrees) are $15,30,60$, then the true average is $35$, but with your proposed method, you would get (approximately) $34.86780516$.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the mean correctly, all your angles need to be in the range $[-180, 180)$. For example, the average of $1, 359, 3$ is $121$, but the average of $1, -1, 3$ is $1$.

Here is some pseudocode that can help you do this:

```
var angles = [354, 357, 355, 2, 352, 4, 352]
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
     if (-180 < i AND i ≤ 180) {
          angles[i] = angles[i]
     }

     if (i > 180}
          angles[i] = angles[i] - 360 * ceil(angles[i]/360)

     }  else {
          angles[i] = angles[i] + 360 * ceil(angles[i]/360)
     }
}
```

and then you can calculate the mean as usual.

Doing this with your dataset gives ${-6, -3, -5, 2, -8, 4, -8}$, and the mean gives $356.5714$. I suspect the difference is because you are rounding your figures to 4 decimal places during the computation.

Comment: No, the difference is due to the bias in the other method. For this example, your method gives the correct average.

Comment: However, your proposed method (i.e., your pseudocode) would fail (in the sense of returning an obviously incorect answer) for the angles $160,170,195$.

Comment: I guess you could change the ranges, such as changing to '0 < i AND i ≤ 360' and 'i > 360' if it doesn't work. I still suspect there will be a counterexample where neither the original range or the changed range will work.